# Make Table cell function like Email's "To:" row in iOS

Tags: ios, email, uitableview

Is it possible to make a table cell function like the "To:" row in the email app?

[image]

For example, something like the following, where the button replaced with the "+". When I start to edit the row, I get same experience as I type in the "To:" row in the email app?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you created a custom UITableCell class? Have you investigated the setSelected method of your class?

Comment: I was trying to duplicate the To: row of the email app. So I can either type email addresses, or select one or more from the contacts.

Comment: I know what you're trying to do. What I'm asking is "what effort have you made on your own, beyond posting asking someone to write the code for you?"

Comment: Well, i suppose when you post something you are expecting someone write code for you. Not my style though. I am trying ABAddressBook ...

Comment: *Well, i suppose when you post something you are expecting someone write code for you.* I think you suppose wrong..

Comment: I could down vote it but why bother losing my -2 over this silly question

Comment: @marsant: indeed, you suppose wrong. when I post a question, I make it clear why I'm having trouble and need help with what I've tried on my own. When you post, it's "please hand me a solution to this." As you said, not my style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you a bit. It is code for adding a button to each table cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
    {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
cell.textLabel.text = [_tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// Create and add the button to the cell
UIButton *theButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[theButton setFrame:CGRectMake(235, 7, 75, 30)];
[theButton setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapButtonInCell) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:theButton];
return cell;
}

-(void)didTapButtonInCell {
// your code here
}
```

Comment: I end up using a disclosure indicator to bring up a ABPeoplePickerNavigationController that let me pick up emails. The didTapButtonInCell() above can do the same. I wanted to use the "+" button used in email app, but could not find it.